# Trouble getting SQL Server subquery to pick desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am given a database to use in SQL server.
The tables are:

- Price (prodID, from, price)
- Product (prodID, name, quantity)
- PO (prodID, orderID, amount)
- Order (orderID, date, address, status, trackingNumber, custID,
  shipID)
- Shipping (shipID, company, time, price)
- Customer (custID, name)
- Address (addrID, custID, address)

**I need to Determine the ID and current price of each product.**

The `from` attribute in the `Price` table are the dates that the prices were updated i.e. each ID in the table has multiple prices and dates associated with them but **there is no common date between all of the IDs** and the dates are in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format and range is from 2018 to 2019-12-31.

My current query looks like:

```
select distinct p.prodID, p.price
from Price as p
where p.[from] >= '2019-12-23' and p.[from] in (select [from]
from Price
group by [from]
having max([from]) <= '2019-12-31')
order by p.prodID;
```

which returns a table with multiple prices for some of the IDs and also excludes other IDs altogether.

I was told that I needed a subquery to perform this.

I believe that I may be being too specific in my query to produce the desired results.

**My main goal is to fix my current query to select one of each `prodID` and `price` from the most recent `from` date.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*, row_number() over(partition by p.prodid order by p.from desc) rn
    from price p
    where p.from <= convert(date, getdate())
) t
where rn = 1
```

This returns the latest row for each `prodid` where `from` is not greater that the current date.

As an alternative, you could also use `with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties p.*
from price p
where p.from <= convert(date, getdate())
order by row_number() over(partition by p.prodid order by p.from desc)
```